# Incompatible Android target device?

Tags: android, sdk

I'm new to Android and was just trying to load a sample project (Bluetooth Chat application) onto my smartphone (running Android 2.3.4). The target build project in Eclipse uses Android API level 15 (Android 4.0.3). When I try "Run as Android Application" with the phone connected, the Android Device chooser indicates that the device in not compatible, and I get the errors shown in the text below. How do I get around this problem? Surely I shouldn't have to downgrade my build target to a lower API level (10) and possible loose functionality?

Btw, the same project includes this in the manifest:

```
<uses-sdk minSdkVersion="6" />
```

.

```
[2012-01-27 19:59:43 - BluetoothChat] Android Launch!
[2012-01-27 19:59:43 - BluetoothChat] adb is running normally.
[2012-01-27 19:59:43 - BluetoothChat] Performing com.example.android.BluetoothChat.BluetoothChat activity launch
[2012-01-27 19:59:43 - BluetoothChat] Automatic Target Mode: Unable to detect device compatibility. Please select a target device.
[2012-01-27 20:00:02 - BluetoothChat] WARNING: Application does not specify an API level requirement!
[2012-01-27 20:00:02 - BluetoothChat] Device API version is 10 (Android 2.3.4)
[2012-01-27 20:00:02 - BluetoothChat] Uploading BluetoothChat.apk onto device '304D1938E5584E7E'
[2012-01-27 20:00:02 - BluetoothChat] Installing BluetoothChat.apk...
[2012-01-27 20:00:03 - BluetoothChat] Re-installation failed due to different application signatures.
[2012-01-27 20:00:03 - BluetoothChat] You must perform a full uninstall of the application. WARNING: This will remove the application data!
[2012-01-27 20:00:03 - BluetoothChat] Please execute 'adb uninstall com.example.android.BluetoothChat' in a shell.
[2012-01-27 20:00:03 - BluetoothChat] Launch canceled!
```

Many thanks :)

Comment: Why would you expect an Android 2.3.4 device to have capabilities from 4.0.3?  And more to the point, why would you expect the SDK to let you write code that won't run on your target device?

Comment: Because I thought minSdkVersion="6" would allow me to run it on my earlier version... ?

Answer (score 2):

```
[2012-01-27 20:00:03 - BluetoothChat] Re-installation failed due to different application signatures.
[2012-01-27 20:00:03 - BluetoothChat] You must perform a full uninstall of the application. WARNING: This will remove the application data!
```

The app already exists on your device, signed with one signing key. You are trying to install over top of it another copy of the same app (i.e., same package) with a different signing key.

Please remove the existing BluetoothChat app from your device (e.g., through Settings), then run the app.

Comment: I have looked high and low on my phone for the app and I can't find it. However, a colleague of mine loaded an app which he based directly on the Bluetooth Chat example... so perhaps that is where the conflict is?

Comment: @GrahamPeyton: It's highly likely that's the case. What Android is really tripping over is an identical package name -- the `package` attribute in your `<manifest>` element in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file. That has to be unique on the device (and on the Market, for that matter). If your colleague cloned BluetoothChat and didn't change the package name, his would have the same package as the one you are trying to load. And, since his would be signed with his signing key, you'd get the error you see here.

Answer (score 1):

The target build for your project should be 10 here, that would allow the project to run on devices >= api 10.

Comment: I guess I'm getting confused between minimum API and target API. If I change it to 10, then that means I can't use functionality from levels > 10. I want to add an action bar which requires API 11, and now I can't -_-

Comment: if u want action bar of api11 that means that app won't run on the phones having <11 api i.e. upto os 2.3..

Answer (score 0):

As it says, the key used to sign the BluetoothChat sample on your phone (maybe a release key?) is different from the one you're using to run it (debug key). Uninstall the app on your phone and (when it's not on your phone) select "Run as Android Application".

You can't upgrade an app (essentially what "Run as Android Application" does) if the keys are not the same.